# Problem with subtitles(.srt) on DVD player

Tags: dvd, subtitles

I want to know why when I use my computer to play a movie (.avi) and subtitles (.srt) the last ones appear centered down of the screen but, when I burn them into a CD and play it in my DVD player the subtitles appear in the lower left corner of the screen. I know that the problem is my DVD player (hitech HT-425) because when I play it in other DVD player subs are centered. Is there any program to me fix this?

I know that there are some programs that allows you to combine the avi file and the srt file in one divx file correcting this error but I want to know if there is any program that allows me just to modify de srt file so the subtitles can appear the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't own your DVD player, but I too have problems with subtitles on my DVD player (a modest AG). It works if I convert the subtitles to a SUB format. MicroDVD on my case.

Since you don't want to mux the subtitles, you have very few options. There's nothing wrong with your srt. This is controlled by your dvd player chipset. Either srt is entirely not supported, or the chipset contains a bug (unfortunately common on many asian-made models). Some hardcore ripping folks on the net know all the details on many of these chipsets. So you may want to open your dvd player, get the chipset make and model and travel to such places like [Doom9](http://forum.doom9.org/), for further info.

Finally, if your DVD player is DivX Certified, you can convert your srt to XSUB. It won't matter if you then mux or not. It will play in that format.

Best of luck.

---

To be clear, there's nothing you can do other than trying to convert your srt to other formats or mux the subtitles.

But since you seem interested in playing ripped videos in your DVD player, let me give you a piece of advise: As soon as possible get yourself a DivX Certified DVD player. There's much better subtitle support on these devices.

Comment: Actually it was my dvd player so I couldn't do much

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called **Hard** or **Prerendered subtitles**.
There are Wikipedia description references in the [Subtitle playback](https://superuser.com/questions/44071/subtitle-playback) question.
I have never tried this but there seems to be [some discussion here](http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-124499.html).